# Receiving and decoding RDS in GnuRadio

Tags: software-defined-radio, gnuradio

I'm new in radio, so I started with seemingly easy task - receive and decode [RDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_Data_System) data. I use GnuRadio to understand the concept of working with RF signals. So according to standard RDS receiver looks this way:
[image: RDS decoder scheme]

I really would love to see how people actually do this in digital systems. I tried to apply a part of this scheme in GnuRadio, so I have this:
[image: GnuRadio RDS decoder first part]

As you can see I took 57kHz signal source to shift RDS spectrum to lower frequencies as in the standard, but what really confuses me is that in standard they use subcarrier recovery module.

As I understand if I don't use subcarrier recovery there will be a phase error in 2.4kHz signal so further demodulating will be impossible.

I tried to use costas loop, PLL carrier Tracking and PLL ref out blocks to recover this 57kHz carrier but I couldn't get any decent output after 2.4kHz low pass filter. Also these blocks have complex inputs but after WBFM receiver the signal is real. I tried to use Hilbert filter, but seems that is wrong.

Summarizing everything up, there are several questions:

1. Am I on the right way to decode RDS signal?
2. How can I use carrier recovery blocks when my signal is real?
3. What do I need to do next after 2.4kHz lowpass filtering? What blocks do I need to use to get a bitstream?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't have time right now, but you are aware of [gr-rds](https://github.com/bastibl/gr-rds), right?

Comment: I edited your question mainly to add a link to the Wikipedia article on RDS.  I hope you don't mind!

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I know about gr-rds, but i'm working on windows so i don't really know how to install it and unfortunately in those videos they don't show the whole graph. Anyway thank you.

Comment: @rclocher3 of course i don't mind, thank you!

Comment: @mishaskt you don't even need to install it to open the flow graphs.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I checked this repo one more time and found some slides where i could see more of graph. And i already have many questions. Actually that is funny because i found many books about basics of RF and not only basics. But when i open GnuRadio i see so many blocks i have never read about or seen. And then i found examples where people use them and i have no idea why. That is really confusing.

Comment: well, that's a good sign, isn't it? Imagine having read a lot about RF and then going into a library about RF stuff and not finding the majority of books to be about something you'Ve not heard about so far!

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks for your hint. I kind of made it, despite my constellation constantly rotates, what confuses me. Everything confuses me. Anyway i still don't understand what i did wrong before.

Comment: How is gr-rds used in GNU radio 3.8? It does not seem to be included?